Is it possible to create a SignalStore which uses union or recursive types?
I would like to use a SignalStore whose state type uses union or recursive types but as ngrx withComputed destructures the state type into multiple signals, I can't access anything.
type Entries = Array<{ fileName: string } | { folderName: string; entries?: Entries }>;

const initialState: Entries = [
  { fileName: 'autoexec.bat' },
  { fileName: 'config.sys' },
  {
    folderName: 'DOS',
    entries: [
      { fileName: 'himem.sys' }
    ]
  }
];

const EntryStore = signalStore(
  withState<Entries>(initialState),
  withComputed(state => ({
    maxLevel: computed(() => state.<NOTHING!!!>)
  }))
);

Is it possible for withComputed to receive the whole state (as a Signal<Entries>) instead of a destructured one (which yields nothing in my case).
